# Careers 2.0 Page not counting work experience

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have provided experience for the last 7 years and yet my score is only 20/25. I have also added 3 projects of mine (not forks) from GitHub and I have received no credit for those either.

Comment: What does you completeness score page say for those entries? (*Maybe Careers knows you've been secretly procrastinating at work?* ;) )

Comment: Technically what’s going on here is that it literally counts calendar years and you have none listed for 2014. But I won’t defend that logic, I’ll work on making it a bit smarter.

Comment: @Bart, 20 / 25 for history, 15 / 20 for projects. And the NSA can confirm that I was at home. :-P

Comment: @ Matt Sherman: I have 7 full years of experience put in, Jauary 2007 to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find that this calculation is better now.

Comment: It is better (experience is calculating correctly now), but it is still not working for linking to open source projects. I have the minimum of 3 and it still hasn't updated the score.

Comment: @Brian should be better now